# How can I load data from controller (JSON) to a ListBox in View?

Tags: json, ajax, asp.net-core, get

I am new in ASP.NET Core. I just want to simply load a JSON file's data into a listbox.

Here is the controller class:

```
 public class EmployeeController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
    [HttpGet]
    public JsonResult GetEmpList()
    {
        var empList = new List<Employee>()
        {
            new Employee { Id=1, Name="Manas"},
            new Employee { Id=2, Name="Tester"}
        };

        return Json(empList);
    }

}
```

And here is the view:

```
<select id="ddlEmployees"></select>
<script>
var ddlEmployees = $("#ddlEmployees");
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "/EmployeeController/GetEmpList",
    dataType: 'JSON',
    contentType: "application/json",
    success: function (data) {
        alert(data);
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            ddlEmployees.append('<option> ' + data[i] + '</option >');
        }
    }
}); </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are successfully able to make requests to your API endpoint I think the part that needs to be updated is actually your jQuery in the view. Since you're returning a list as JSON, what you'll have in your `data` argument is an array of objects. So in order to populate the values of the `<option>` tag with the values in your JSON object, you'll need to access the JSON fields that you define in your Controller.

```
<select id="ddlEmployees"></select>
<script>
var ddlEmployees = $("#ddlEmployees");
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "/EmployeeController/GetEmpList",
    dataType: 'JSON',
    contentType: "application/json",
    success: function (data) {
        alert(data);
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            ddlEmployees.append('<option value="' + data[i].Id + '"> ' + data[i].Name + '</option >');
        }
    }
}); </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The naming convention for response json in asp.net core is **camel case** instead of pascal case.

You could add `console.log(data)` to check the response in `Console` panel(press F12 in browser). Then you will find the property name in response is **camel case**.

Change like below:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "/Employee/GetEmpList",   //it should be Employee/xxx instead of EmployeeController/xxx
    dataType: 'JSON',
    contentType: "application/json",
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
            ddlEmployees.append('<option value="' + data[i].id + '"> ' + data[i].name + '</option >');
        }
    }
});
```